# How can I apply a ternary operator in this code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to apply a ternary operator on this block of code and insert another if the condition is false. I find it a bit confusing because I've never used a ternary operator in this type of code blocks.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
{isNormalLoader && (
      <Dimmer active inverted>
        <Loader size="medium">{!textDisabled && loadingText}</Loader>
      </Dimmer>
)}
```

If the condition is false, display other component, but I don't have any clue on how to do it.

Comment: `If the condition is false` wich condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this

`{condition ? trueComponent : falseComponent}`

For Your code:

```
{isNormalLoader ? <Dimmer active inverted><Loader size="medium">{!textDisabled && loadingText}</Loader></Dimmer> : <ForFalseComponent/>}
```

Comment: Going to mark this one as a valid one, 8 minutes till stack overflow lets me, thanks!